# How to filter inner arrays from multi-dimensional array

Tags: ios, arrays, alamofire, swifty-json, dollar.swift

I am trying to pull out variables (`safety_rating_id`, `score` etc.) from an array (called `array`) based on the `submission_id` using the swift library `Dollar` (https://github.com/ankurp/Dollar)'s  `find` method so that I can later make a POST request (Eventually, I hope to be able to replace the hardcoded values in my parameter with the pulled array variables) with them but my results from `find` all return nil.

These are the inner arrays I want where the `submission_id` is `27` from this array https://codeshare.io/zr1pw (lines 22- 36):

```
{
 "submission_id" : "27",
 "name" : "Equipment",
 "task_id" : "37",
 "points" : "10",
 "safety_rating_id" : 105,
 "score" : "9"
}, {
 "submission_id" : "27",
 "name" : "Emergency Equipment",
 "task_id" : "37",
 "points" : "10",
 "safety_rating_id" : 106,
"score" : "9"
}
```

Code:

```
  var array: [JSON] = []   
  func submitScore(onCompletion: () -> (), onError: ((NSError) -> ())? = nil) {

    guard let endPoint = Data.sharedInstance.submitScoreEndpoint
        else { print("Empty endpoint"); return }

    let user = Users()

    let test = $.find(self.array, callback: { $0 == 27 })
    print(test)

    let Auth_header = [
        "Authorization" : user.token,
        ]

    let parameters: [String:Array<[String:Int]>] = [
        "ratings" : [
            [
                "safety_rating_id" : 105,
                "schedule_job_id" : 18,
                "score" : 9,
                "submission_id" : 27
            ],
            [
                "safety_rating_id" : 106,
                "schedule_job_id" : 18,
                "score" : 10,
                "submission_id" : 27
            ]
        ]
    ]


Alamofire.request(.POST, endPoint, headers: Auth_header, parameters: parameters, encoding: .JSON)
        .validate()
        .responseJSON {
        response in

        switch response.result {
        case .Success(let data):
            let json = JSON(data)
            print(json)
            onCompletion()
        case .Failure(let error):
            print("Request failed with error: \(error)")
            onError?(error)
        }

    }

}
```

**UPDATE**

I'm able to obtain the array with `submission_id` 27 BUT I want to remove `name` and `task_id` from the two `submission_id : 27` arrays *AND* add an `schedule_job_id` that I got from elsewhere.

I've tried using a `for in` loop to create my own array from the variables that I want but I keep getting a `nil` crash. This is what the new array looks like https://codeshare.io/3VJSo

[image: for in loop error]

Eventually I want to do a `"ratings" : [chosenArray]`

Comment: Why are you calling `.validate()` twice?

Comment: oh I didnt notice that thanks for pointing out

Comment: you have another similar question that I have answered: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37540689/how-to-identify-specific-values-in-json-response

Answer (score 3):

So what gets passed inside of the callback is each element in the array so you will get passed the dictionary object. So if you want to find a specific item in the array you should do

```
let test = $.find(array) { $0["submission_id"]! == "27" }
```

If you want all elements in array that have submission id as 27 then use `filter`

```
let test = array.filter { $0["submission_id"]! == "27" }
```

To remove properties from a dictionary object you need to call `removeValueForKey` method on each item on the array.

```
let jsonWithMySubmissionId = self.array.filter ({ $0["submission_id"]! == 27 })
for json in jsonWithMySubmissionId {
  json.removeValueForKey("name")
  json.removeValueForKey("task_id")
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you are using `$` wrong.
When you call `$.find` on `self.array` the array contains JSON objects, not sure what the object exactly is, but I assume it's Dictionary. 
So I think you should do something like:

```
let jsonWithMySubmissionId = self.array.filter ({ $0["submission_id"]! == 27 }).first
```

Then, I would avoid that force unwrap on the dictionary. It was just for you to understand my point in one line of code.

**Edit:**

Then you can iterate over the array and extract your fields like this:

```
let jsonWithMySubmissionId = self.array.filter ({ $0["submission_id"]! == 27 })
for json in jsonWithMySubmissionId {
  json["name"] = nil
  json["task_id"] = nil
  ...
}
```

Comment: Hi do you know how I can remove the `name` and `task_id` from each of the arrays generated (see updated post)

Comment: See my edit on the original post, if it solved your problem please consider accepting that answer

Answer (score 2):

Your `dic` in your for loop must be type of `NSMutableDictionary`. Because you can't manipulate `NSDictionary`.

Second thing there is no method like `removeValueForKey`.

You should use `removeObjectForKey` or `removeObjectsForKeys`.

In `removeObjectsForKeys` you have to pass array of parameters (keys as parameter).

In `removeObjectForKey` you can pass one string (key) as parameter.